# How to hide a section with default content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my Master I have a section with default content:

```
@section BlahBlah {
  <p>Hello world!</p>
}
```

Now in my view pages, for some of them, I want to hide this section completely.

How can I do this?

Comment: what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in function called `IsSectionDefined` that will let you default the content if the given section name hasn't been defined. You can see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx) for more details.

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("BlahBlah")) {
    @RenderSection("BlahBlah")
} else {
    <p>Hello world!</p>
}
```